# Black and Scholes model find price at $t=0$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

**Problem:**

We have a framework of the Black and Scholes model.

I would like to find the price at $T=0$ of some asset. This asset pays $X_T=S^2_T/S_{T/2}$ at time $T$, where $S_T$ is a price of one share at time $T$.

**My attempt**

I don't really know from where to approach this question, but I suppose that I have to calculate $\mathbb{E}_*(exp(−rT)X_T)$, but that doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Why write $X_{t}$ for $(S_{T})^{2}/ S_{(T/2)}$? There is no little $t$ in there

Comment: @Ali, fixed it, thank you

Comment: Anyway you could try something along these lines: $$\mathbb{E}\left[(S_{T})^{2} / S_{T/2}\right]=
\int \mathbb{E}\left[(S_{T})^{2}/s \mid
  S_{T/2}=s \right]p\left(S_{T/2}=s\right)ds$$